# PostgreSQL: What is the maximum number of tables can store in postgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql

Q1: What is the maximum number of tables can store in database?

Q2: What is the maximum number of tables can union in view?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Q1: There's no explicit limit in [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/about/). In practice, some operations are O(n) on number of tables; expect planning times to increase, and problems with things like autovacuum as you get to many thousands or tens of thousands of tables in a database.

Q2: It depends on the query. Generally, huge unions are a bad idea. Table inheritance will work a little better, but if you're using `constraint_exclusion` will result in greatly increased planning times.

Both these questions suggest an underlying problem with your design. You shouldn't *need* massive numbers of tables, and giant unions.

Going by the comment in the other answer, you should really just be creating a few tables. You seem to want to create one table per phone number, which is nonsensical, and to create views per number on top of that. Do not do this, it's mismodelling the data and will make it harder, not easier, to work with. Indexes, where clauses, and joins will allow you to use the data more effectively when it's logically structured into a few tables. I suggest studying basic relational modelling.

If you run into scalability issues later, you can look at [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html), but you won't need thousands of tables for that.

Comment: Biggest database I've ever seen was a JD Edwards (I think) ERP system. It had about 20,000 tables running on Oracle.  But that's definitely an outlier.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' It's not too unusual to see much higher table counts thanks to the (ab)use of `search_path` for poor man's partitioning, where the schema is cloned per-customer.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I didn't think about that. I don't work much with multi-tenant architectures. (And I'm grateful, kind of.)

Answer (score 3):

Both are, in a practical sense, without limit.

The number of tables a database can hold is restricted by the space on your disk system. However, having a database with more than a few thousand tables is probably more an expression of an incorrect analysis of your application domain. Same goes for unions: if you have to union more than a handful of tables you probably should look at your table structure.

One practical scenario where this can happen is with Postgis: having many tables with similar attributes that could be joined in a single view (this is a flaw in the design of Postgis IMHO), but that would typically be handled at the application side (e.g. a GIS).

Can you explain your scenario where you would need a very large number of tables that need to be queried in one sweep?

Comment: Scenario is like this: I want to create a database for example called as "Call Details Recorder". Here i want to store the number tables for each called number and tower numbers differently which should be in millions also. And i also want to create views for each called number separately for further quries.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to store mobile telephone conversations, recording which number called another number and through which towers these calls were registered? If so, then you want a single table for the towers, a single table for all telephone numbers with caller name and other details that you have. Both tables have a primary key and then you make a third table that records caller pkey, receiver pkey, tower pkey, time of call, duration, etc. Creating the views is then very simple. Where do you think you need very many tables?

Comment: @user3382347 Yeah, that sounds like you need four or five tables, not thousands. Don't create views for each number, use an SQL function, or a simple `where` clause. You might need to [partition your tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) at scale, but you won't need (or want) thousands of tables for that.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a hard limit for the number of tables/relations in postgresql. There can be at max 1,431,650,303 relations per database. There are other hard limits as well you can see all of them [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html)