# Can postgres store massive amounts of tables? 50,000 for example

Tags: postgresql, postgis

We're building a GIS application based on PostGIS.
We need to store tens of thousands of unique spatial tables which are required by the customer needs. 
The software will allow each register user to create and design his own table by the different needs of each users. The tables will be allowed to download locally by the users as well.

Did anyone experience postgres with such massive table amount?
How's the performance?
What are the hardware requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: What is the maximum number of tables can store in postgreSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395883/postgresql-what-is-the-maximum-number-of-tables-can-store-in-postgresql-databas)

Comment: While it certainly _can_ store that many tables, this has the smell of a poorly designed data model. I can't imagine any properly normalized model with that many tables.

Comment: The intention of the software is to allow a collaborative data collection. Each user will design his own table with the required fields etc. The mentioned duplicate didn't give us the answer we need. Did anyone had an experience with such database?

Comment: *"Each user will design his own table . . . "* What could *possibly* go wrong? (IME, end users make poor designers.)

Comment: Even a customised schema can be abstracted to be stored inside a normalised schema. The only time when you need to define a schema is when you write code against it; if customers can define their own schemas, are they also going to write code that interacts with that schema? Otherwise, what code is going to know how to interact with that customised schema? If there's no code to interact with that database, then it's only a plain datastore and not really integrated into your application?

Comment: You would have to use a distributed database... if you handle all in one server it wont work. You can check  [Citus](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2017/09/15/how-citus-works/) or other distribution service for postgreSQL.

Comment: `50000` tables is not that much, but the number of tables is not a key metric in database performance. It doesn't say anything about the quantity of data and churn rate happening.

Comment: Just don't do it. Rethink your model. Maybe use several databases.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. How will several databases will help? Does it mean that postgres will lose performance in a case of a single database? Users will define the required fields for the geographic locations they need to collect. Those tables will work offline and will enabled to download as well, hence the need for unique table for each user which will save the users definitions

Comment: Hmm, how many records will go into each table? Could the "tables" actually just be a jsonb data type column, that stores all the user specific data?