# PostgreSQL error: too many range table entries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

When I try to execute a large sql queries with 20000 union, PostgreSQL exits with this error: "too many range table entries"

Can you please help me to solve this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
p2.s AS att_X,
p3.s AS att_Y
FROM t_58815 AS p0,
t_27700 AS p1,
t_85383 AS p2,
t_27700 AS p3,
t_50436 AS p4,
t_36552 AS p5
WHERE 
p3.o=p0.o AND p4.o=p1.o AND p2.s=p1.s AND p2.s=p0.s AND p3.s=p4.s AND p3.s=p5.s
UNION ...
```

Comment: What's the large query? Why 20000 union? Union over what?

Comment: twenty thousand queries for a union? Why on earth are you doing that? Rather than fighting that error you should take a step back and describe the underlying problem that you are trying to solve with that.

Comment: The solution really is to redesign. Even if you change any system var to run that, the performance will be... dreadful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: What is the maximum number of tables can store in postgreSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395883/postgresql-what-is-the-maximum-number-of-tables-can-store-in-postgresql-databas)

Comment: you can see the example of this error in the slide number 24 from https://www.slideshare.net/hansjurgenschonig/postgresql-joining-1-million-tables

Comment: Please do **not** post code in comments. **[edit]** your question instead

Answer (score 3):

The only possible solution for this error is to use fewer tables in the `UNION` query.